# Round a double/float in Swift (2 digits)

Tags: swift, alamofire, rounding, swift5

I'm really confused because I'm trying to round a number in Swift and if I run my code on playground I have my number rounded perfectly but if I use "parameters" to send it in Alamofire I don't have my number rounded... Any idea with this issue?. These are my attempts to round my number :(

ATTEMPT 1

```
        var orderTotal = 0.0
        
        orderTotal = Double(total * 100).rounded()/100

   let parameters: [String: Any?] = [
            "Total": orderTotal
    ]
```

ATTEMPT 2

```
 let parameters: [String: Any?] = [
            "Total": total.rounded(digits: 2)
    ]

extension Double {
    func rounded(digits: Int) -> Double {
        let multiplier = pow(10.0, Double(digits))
        return (self * multiplier).rounded() / multiplier
    }
}
```

ATTEMPT 3

```
 let parameters: [String: Any?] = [
            "Total": Float(String(format:"%.2f", (total)))
    ]
```

PS. "total" is a Float parameter with 6-8 decimals

Comment: I could not reproduce the issue you're describing. The rounding worked for me using any of the 3 code snippets you shared here.

Comment: @Jobert it depends on the value. Generally you'll see the problems with values like 1.1 that are repeating fractions in binary, but not in decimal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doubles and floats are binary floating-point. They do not round to decimal values; they round to binary values. If you want a decimal value, use a [Decimal](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/decimal).

Answer (score 1):

This worked for my guys, special thanks to everyone who answered me:

```
var orderTotal = NSDecimalNumber(string: String(total))        
orderTotal = orderTotal.round(2)


extension NSDecimalNumber {
    public func round(_ decimals:Int) -> NSDecimalNumber {
        return self.rounding(accordingToBehavior: NSDecimalNumberHandler(roundingMode: .plain,
            scale: Int16(decimals),raiseOnExactness: false,
            raiseOnOverflow: false,raiseOnUnderflow: false,
            raiseOnDivideByZero: false))
    }
}
```

Comment: FWIW, we generally use `Decimal` in Swift, not `NSDecimalNumber`.