# How to prevent currency with decimal rounds in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

Seems to be trivial but I couldn't figure out how to prevent the currency value from Rounding in Swift.

Below is my code:

```
let halfYearlyPrice = 71.99
var perMonthPrice = (halfYearlyPrice as Double) / 6.0

let currencyFormatter = NumberFormatter()
currencyFormatter.usesGroupingSeparator = true
currencyFormatter.numberStyle = .currency
currencyFormatter.locale = Locale.init(identifier: "en-US")

if let formattedPrice = currencyFormatter.string(from: perMonthPrice as NSNumber) {
    print("formattedPrice: ", formattedPrice)
    print("\(formattedPrice) / month")
}
```

The output is

```
formattedPrice:  $12.00
$12.00 / month
```

I'm wondering how can I ensure the formattedPrice is `11.99`?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The correct tool here is `Decimal` rather than `Double`. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39770303/swift-issue-in-converting-string-to-double/39777334#39777334 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65943363/round-a-double-float-in-swift-2-digits/65943498#65943498 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69199798/round-decimal-to-nearest-increment-given-a-number/69199973#69199973 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33712719/when-is-it-better-to-use-an-nsdecimal-nsdecimalnumber-instead-of-a-double/33712818#33712818

Comment: Rounding to the nearest 2 decimal values gives 12 so you need to round down, `currencyFormatter.roundingMode = .down`

Comment: I disagree with the decision to close this as a duplicate of the "is floating point math broken" thread. That thread alludes to the root cause of these sorts of problems, but for doing math with money, the `Decimal` type is the correct tool (as Rob says in his comment.) There might be an answer in the duplicate question that mentions `Decimal`, but that should be the CENTRAL part of the answer to this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you should use `Decimal` to more accurately represent base-10 values, using a double isn't the root cause of your problem here.

The default `roundingMode` of a `NumberFormatter` is [`.halfEven`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/numberformatter/roundingmode/halfeven), which is going to round 11.998 up to 12.00.  In fact any value >= 11.995 will end up as 12.00.

You need to set the rounding mode to `.down`.

```
let halfYearlyPrice = Decimal(71.99)
var perMonthPrice =  halfYearlyPrice / 6

let currencyFormatter = NumberFormatter()
currencyFormatter.usesGroupingSeparator = true
currencyFormatter.numberStyle = .currency
currencyFormatter.locale = Locale.init(identifier: "en-US")
currencyFormatter.roundingMode = .down

if let formattedPrice = currencyFormatter.string(from: perMonthPrice as NSNumber) {
    print("formattedPrice: ", formattedPrice)
    print("\(formattedPrice) / month")
}
```

Output:

> formattedPrice:  $11.99
>
> $11.99 / month

You will get this result even if you don't use `Decimal`, but rounding errors can accrue if you perform numerous currency operations using floating point values rather than `Decimal`.

Comment: So `currencyFormatter.roundingMode = .down` was the key to the solution I was looking. Thank you so much for the tip!